# Confused about Optional vs Default value -1

Tags: swift, coding-style, option-type, default-value

We are working in a Swift project. A function was there like,

```
fun getSleepAmmount() -> Int {
    // calculate sleep time
    // return value when valid
    // else
    return -1
}
```

My team member prefers the above function where caller needs to check with `-1` which is not I am comfortable with. My suggestion is to redesign with `nil` return (although callers still need to check nullability) like,

```
fun getSleepAmmount() -> Int? {
    // calculate sleep time
    // return value when valid
    // else
    return nil
}
```

But my colleagues do not want to redesign. Which version of the functions is cleaner and why?

Comment: Obviously the optional version is cleaner (see the answers), but your colleagues may be concerned that it would be changing an API which might have knock on effects in terms of testing and changes elsewhere.

Comment: @JeremyP It has not so many callers yet.

Comment: If it's a new function, the optional version is definitely the right way to go. If your colleague really needs his `-1` he can write `getSleepAmount() ?? -1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, `nil` is much cleaner. Because of `-1` means nothing. This is just a magic word. It is difficult to support, refactor and handle this case.

Answer (score 2):

Second is the better as youll do

```
if let v = getSleepAmmount() {}
```

But with First

```
 let v =  getSleepAmmount() 
 if v > 0 {}
```

Returning nil means this isn't a valid return while -1 may mean another thing that will be miss-understood by a new developer that checks the code

Answer (score 2):

Returning `nil` is a better solution instead of using any *garbage or default* value.

Returning any *default value* may in future clash with the actual result.

Also, there might be other developers dealing with the same code. So, using `nil` will have a better explanation than using `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

If there is code in the caller that should only run if there is a valid sleep amount, then optionals is the better and clearer way to go. This is exactly what `guard let` and `if let` are designed for:

```
guard let sleepAmount = getSleepAmount() { else return }

// do something with sleepAmount
```

An even better way would be to throw an error inside the function:

```
func getSleepAmmount() throws -> Int {
    // calculate sleep time
    // return when valid
    // else
    throw InvalidSleepAmount
}
```

Then

```
do {
    let sleepAmount = try getSleepAmount()
    // do something with it
} catch InvalidSleepAmount {
    // error processing
}
```

(If you want, your function could throw different errors so the caller gets to know *why* the sleep amount is invalid, `SleepTooShort`, `SleepTooLong`, `NoSleep` etc)

Comment: Exceptions aren't useful. They just 'another return'. It's difficult to handle them if the logic is complicated.

Comment: Exception can be good if there are multiple unwanted states arise and caller needs to know specific states of the function to handle differently. In my case returning `nil` is enough to let caller know single invalid state.